# How to query conversation summary with Users and Show Latest Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, chat

I have a chat application and in a sidebar. I need to show all the users names and the last message from my conversation with them with Entity Framework. Following is the Entity Object

```
public partial class ObjectMessage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FromUserId { get; set; }
    public int ToUserId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateSent { get; set; }
    public bool Unread { get; set; }

}
```

I experimented with following query but it didn't produced the desired result.

```
            var messages = db.ObjectMessages.Where(x => x.ToUserId == userId || x.FromUserId == userId)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateSent)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.ToUserId, x.FromUserId })
            .Select(x => new LastMessage
            {
                FromUserId = x.FirstOrDefault().FromUserId,
                ToUserId = x.FirstOrDefault().ToUserId,
                Body  = x.FirstOrDefault().Body,
                DateSent = x.FirstOrDefault().DateSent,
                Me = x.FirstOrDefault().FromUserId == userId,
                Unread = x.Count(i=> i.Unread)
            }).OrderBy(x=> x.DateSent).ToList();
```

My user id is in both the properties (From/To). May be the Table structure is not the best approach or there must be a good way to achieve result. Please advise.

Comment: By the way I have a separate list of Users where I will append each last message to its related user.

Comment: You need both last message when you are the `FromUserId`, then `ToUserId` and combine them into something like `Dictionary<UserId, message>`?

Comment: I need the latest message out of those both whichever, whether I am FromUserId or ToUserId. The purpose of this is that I out put all friend list names and under the each name I have to show the last message from conversation whether it is from me or him.

Comment: You only need to see if your posted the last message or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following test data:

```
var messages = new List<ObjectMessage>();
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1000, Body = "AAA", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 01, 14, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 1, ToUserId = 6 });
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1001, Body = "BBB", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 01, 14, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 3, ToUserId = 2 });
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1002, Body = "CCC", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 01, 14, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 7, ToUserId = 6 });
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1003, Body = "DDD", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 01, 15, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 1, ToUserId = 6 });
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1004, Body = "EEE", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 02, 18, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 2, ToUserId = 3 });
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1005, Body = "FFF", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 01, 14, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 1, ToUserId = 7 });
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1006, Body = "GGG", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 02, 20, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 8, ToUserId = 9 });
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1007, Body = "HHH", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 03, 11, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 9, ToUserId = 8 });
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1008, Body = "III", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 03, 12, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 8, ToUserId = 1 });
messages.Add(new ObjectMessage { Id = 1009, Body = "JJJ", DateSent = new DateTime(2017, 03, 13, 0, 0, 0), Unread = false, FromUserId = 7, ToUserId = 8 });
```

First group the data with you as sender:

```
 var messagesAsSender = messages
     .Where(p => p.FromUserId == 8)
     .GroupBy(p => new { Me = p.FromUserId, Him = p.ToUserId })
     .ToDictionary(
         p => p.Key,
         p => p.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateSent)
               .FirstOrDefault());
```

Secondly group the data with you as receiver:

```
var messagesAsReceiver = messages
    .Where(p => p.ToUserId == 8)
    .GroupBy(p => new { Me = p.ToUserId, Him = p.FromUserId })
    .ToDictionary(
        p => p.Key,
        p => p.OrderByDescending(t => t.DateSent)
              .FirstOrDefault());
```

Finally compare them and get the last message:

```
var messagesLast = messagesAsSender
    .Concat(messagesAsReceiver)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Key)
    .ToDictionary(
        p => p.Key,
        p => p.OrderByDescending(date => date.Value.DateSent)
              .FirstOrDefault()
              .Value
              .Body);
```

Comment: Thanks Cristian Szpisjak. it is looking cool. I will test it and mark this question as answered.